# How many types of Cache is there in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How many types of cache is there in asp.net and how can implement it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is 1 Cache object, that you can use more or less like the Application object

And there is Output caching, per page or per user control.

You would use the Cache object like this (there are overloads):

```
Cache.Insert("myKey", myValue,  null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
   System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

And for outputcaching, you can use this line below the `<%@ Page %>` line:

```
 <%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="myParam"%>
```

Comment: And other forms of State Management can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Comment: Another overview of persistence, 9 options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S8

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CacheManager http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx from the Enterprise Library or if you want a distributed cache you can go for Memcached http://memcached.org/